# I need a Java regular expression

Tags: java, regex

I am currently using the following regular expression:

```
^[a-zA-Z]{0,}(\\*?)?[a-zA-Z0-9]{0,}
```

to check a string to start with an alpha character and end with alphanumeric characters and have an asterisk(*) anywhere in the string but only a maximum of one time. The problem here is that if the given string still passes if it starts with a number but doesn't have an *, which should fail. How can I rework the regex to fail this case?

ex.

```
TE - pass

*TE - pass

TE* - pass

T*E - pass

*9TE - pass

*TE* - fail (multiple asterisk)

9E - fail (starts with number)
```

EDIT:
Sorry to introduce a late edit but I also need to ensure that the string is 8 characters or less, can I include that in the regex as well? Or should I just check the string length after the regex validation?

Comment: I would just check the length before or after validation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This passes your example:

```
"^([a-zA-Z]+\\*?|\\*)[a-zA-Z0-9]*$"

It says:
  start with: [a-zA-Z]+\\*? (a letter and maybe a star)
              | (or)
              \\* a single star
  and end with [a-zA-Z0-9]* (an alphanumeric character)
```

Code to test it:

```
public static void main(final String[] args) {
    final Pattern p = Pattern.compile("^([a-zA-Z]+\\*?|\\*)\\w*$");

    System.out.println(p.matcher("TE").matches());
    System.out.println(p.matcher("*TE").matches());
    System.out.println(p.matcher("TE*").matches());
    System.out.println(p.matcher("T*E").matches());
    System.out.println(p.matcher("*9TE").matches());
    System.out.println(p.matcher("*TE*").matches());
    System.out.println(p.matcher("9E").matches());
}
```

Per Stargazer, if you allow alphanumeric before the star, then use this:

```
^([a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]*\\*?|\\*)\\w*$
```

Comment: @NKCSS, it passes T*E just fine, but it fails on T9*Z. Changing it to `^([a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]*\\*?|\\*)\\w*$` should do the trick.

Comment: Deleted it, must have added it to the wrong regex (there were quite a lot here with issues) :)

Comment: @Stargazer I read it as all the alphanumeric characters should be after the star, if that's not the case, then yeah

Comment: @Reverand Gonzo, true. Depends on what the author meant I guess...Nice solution

Comment: Thank you, this works but I already implemented @KennyTM 's solution, and @Stargazer712 was correct, it need only start with an alpha character after that any alphanumeric or wildcard

Comment: Using \w also matches an underscore, so that's not really nice. You should use [a-zA-Z0-9]

Comment: when I use  ^([a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]*\\*?\\*)[a-zA-z0-9]*$  it still fails with underscore

Comment: `^([a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]*\*?|\*)[a-zA-z0-9]*$`

Comment: @Erik, in: [a-zA-z0-9], the second z should be capital.

Comment: @Reverend Gonzo, thanks, that fixed it, I can't believe I missed that when I proofread it

Answer (score 1):

One possible way is to separate into 2 conditions:

```
^(?=[^*]*\*?[^*]*$)[a-zA-Z*][a-zA-Z0-9*]*$
```

- The `(?=[^*]*\*?[^*]*$)` part ensures there is at most one `*` in the string.
- The `[a-zA-Z*][a-zA-Z0-9*]*` part ensures it starts with an alphabet or a `*`, and followed by only alphanumerals or `*`.

Comment: Okay, it looks like this is working but Eclipse says there is an illegal escape sequece, should I just double the '\' before the '*'?

Comment: @Erik, I warn you against using a look ahead if you don't need it. They are more difficult to read and have less support. Reverand Gonzo's solution is probably the most straightforward solution.

Answer (score 0):

It might be easier to develop and maintain later if you just break your regular expressions into a few pieces, e.g., one for the start and end, and one for the asterisk.  I am not sure what the overall performance effect would be, you would have simpler expressions but have to run a few of them.

Answer (score 0):

Look for two possible patterns, one starting with *, and one with an alpha char:

```
^[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]*(\\*?)?[a-zA-Z0-9]*|\*[a-zA-Z0-9]*
```

Comment: Regex constructor threw an exception:
parsing "^[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9](\?)?[a-zA-Z0-9]|*[a-zA-Z0-9]" - Quantifier {x,y} following nothing.

Comment: Thanks - hadn't marked it as code, and SO was hiding some chars.

Answer (score 0):

How about this, it's easier to read:

```
boolean pass = input.replaceFirst("\\*", "").matches("^[a-zA-Z].*\\w$");
```

Assuming I read right, you want to:

1. Start with an alpha character
2. End with an alphanumeric character
3. Allow up to one `*` anywhere

Answer (score 0):

`^([a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]*\*|\*|[a-zA-Z])([a-zA-Z0-9])*$`

the parenthesis around the second half are for clarity and can be safely excluded.

Comment: Eek...just realized that mine requires exactly one star...challenging

Answer (score 0):

This was a tough one (liked the challenge), but here it is:

```
^(\*[a-zA-Z0-9]+|[a-zA-Z]+[\*]{1}[a-zA-Z]*)$
```

In order to comply with T9*Z, as pointed out on another post with StarGazer712, I had to change it to:

```
^(\*[a-zA-Z0-9]+|[a-zA-Z]{1}[a-zA-Z0-9]*[\*]{1}[a-zA-Z0-9]*)$
```

Answer (score 0):

This is Python, it'll need some massaging for Java:

```
>>> import re
>>> p = re.compile('^([a-z][^*]*[*]?[^*]*[a-z0-9]|[*][^*]*[a-z0-9]|[a-z][^*]*[*])$', re.I)
>>> for test in ['TE', '*TE', 'TE*', 'T*E', '*9TE', '*TE*', '9E']:
...  if p.match(test):
...   print test, 'pass'
...  else:
...   print test, 'fail'
... 
TE pass
*TE pass
TE* pass
T*E pass
*9TE pass
*TE* fail
9E fail
```

Hope I didn't miss anything.

Answer (score 0):

At most one asterisk, alphabetic characters anywhere and numbers anywhere but at start.

```
    String alpha = "[a-zA-Z]";
    String alnum = "[a-zA-Z0-9]";

    String asteriskNone = "^" + alpha + "+" + alnum + "*";
    String asteriskStart = "^\\*" + alnum + "*";
    String asteriskInside = "^" + alpha + "+" + alnum + "+\\*" + alnum + "*";
    String yourRegex = asteriskNone + "|" + asteriskStart + "|"
            + asteriskInside;
    String[] tests = {"TE","*TE","TE*","T*E","*9TE","*TE*", "9E"};
    for (String test : tests)
        System.out.println(test + " " + (test.matches(yourRegex)?"PASS":"FAIL"));
```